# getting edittext.settext data from textwatcher in android

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textwatcher

I am setting the text in `EditText` but when getting the text from `TextWatcher` it is giving empty string.

Please  check this code

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
   et = new EditText(this);
   et.setText("hai");
   final EditText finalEt = et;
   ans.addView(et);
   final int finalI = i;
   finalEt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
       public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
           Log.d("text is",""+finalEt.getText().toString());
       }

       public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,int count, int after) {}

       public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,int before, int count) {}
   }
```

Comment: please check for different conditions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get it in `onTextChanged` as well as on `afterTextChanged` something like this.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
et = new EditText(this);
et.setText("hai");

final EditText finalEt = et;

ans.addView(et);
final int finalI = i;
finalEt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                   String str = s.toString();
           Log.d("text is",""+s);

   }

   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,int count, int after) {}

   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,int before, int count) {
           Log.d("text is",""+s.toString());
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but if i want to get only "hai" from the Log.d

Comment: Sorry but not getting you. AT this moment what do you get? `s.toString()` will return you text you have entered in `edittext.`

Comment: it is displaying hai+data entered in edittext               but i need only the "hai" which is set from et.setText("hai") from the log message

Comment: If you just want to get the text you entered previously then what is the use of using `TextWatcher `?  And If you want to get text before you started entering then you can get it on `beforeTextChanged ` method by ` String str = s.toString();`

Comment: actually in my app an activity has four edittexts to collect user info ,initially they are empty but after filled-in by user ,his info will be saved and he goes to next activity and if he wants to change the info. he come back to the activity since the info is already filled-in i will set those data in the edittext  but if he changes only one out  of four , the changed data in the edittext is saving but unchanged edittext is not saving because textWatcher is not being called

Answer (score 0):

Replace log with this

```
Log.d("text is","" + new String(s.toString()));
```